# How to muffle sound coming through a 5" diameter vent hose

Tags: sound-proofing

I have a portable air conditioner with dual insulated hoses to a window. I've captured the cold output with a rectangle-to-round duct transition and some tape into a 5" diameter hose. That hose goes through a wall into a smaller room. The goal is to keep the smaller room cool and quieter. Cooling is working great, but there is a lot of sound coming through the hose. Is there something I could do to muffle that sound without adversely affecting airflow? I thought maybe some type of foam, but I'm concerned about it restricting the airflow.

Comment: Are you trying to block the noise in the room where the the AC is? Or in the room where the hose output is? And is the room where the hose outputs open to the outside so the hose's heat and humidity can dissipate?

Comment: Can you link the model of machine? Are you saying this machine has 3 ducts? Two to the window for intake and discharge, then one to the distal area its intending to cool? And your complaint is that the third duct, which spans 5' or 10' or... is creating too much noise?

Comment: I updated the question. I realize the confusion is because portable AC units don't have hose outputs. I taped a duct transition to the AC unit and have a cold output hose going out from it. And yes, my question is how to reduce the noise that travels through the inside of a 5" diameter hose.

Comment: Does the hose have a smooth interior, or it is flexi-hose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic concept of a duct muffler is to slow the air down and provide some sound-absorbing material, in a manner that does not permit air to pass through without interacting with that - though there are variants where that's permitted, but over a long enough length that most sounds will be affected by the damping.

You can purchase premade mufflers for ducts.

If you are passing through a wall, and it's of ordinary studwall construction, you can use the passage through the wall as part of your muffler. You'll want to maintain an open path of 20 square inches or more (preferably more) to equal or exceed the duct area. A typical **2x4 on 16** studwall has actual spaces between the studs of 3.5x14.5 (3.5x22.5 for studs on 24" centers) giving a bit more than 50 (or 78) square inches. If your duct enters on one side of the wall and then the air travels up or down the stud cavity for some distance, with rockwool insulation (good performance both for fire and for sound) set to the edges, and perhaps also as (partial) baffles from side to side forcing a sinuous flow pattern, considerable reduction in noise (more high-frequency than low-frequency will be reduced) will take place. If the exit from the wall cavity as muffler is larger than 5" diameter, the velocity will be reduced and limit the production of additional noise.

Comment: A duct muffler is exactly what I was looking for. To test out the concept, I built a makeshift one out of a cardboard box and some acoustic foam squares I already had and it made a significant difference. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is wind noise, you need a smooth pipe, as the others said.

If your problem is that the noise from the AC's fan and compressor propagates through the pipe and comes out at the other end, then you need a pipe that prevents sound propagation:

[image]

This is a very soft type of air duct used for ventilation in Europe. It's made of PVC membrane with a wire coil to hold it together. Due to the soft pliable walls, sound tends to go through the pipe walls and out of the pipe instead of propagating inside it and coming out at the end. There's also an insulated version.

Another solution is to build a muffler: a big box with the inside lined with sound absorbent material.

Answer (score 0):

The smoother the output hose is, the less wind noise there will be.

Since you mention a 5" *hose* I'm presuming that it's flexible duct, therefore you're getting a lot of turbulence in the air and that's what you're hearing.

Replace the flexible duct with 5" rigid duct work and it should be much more quiet.

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion. Yes, it is the plastic flexible duct that is usually the exhaust hose for the AC (I repurposed it) so it is not smooth. Would replacing with smooth/rigid ducts help even considering:
1) The hose run is rather short with a 90 degree corner in it. Maybe 1-2 feet up and 1-2 feet over.
2) Would there still be turbulence from the source fan even through a short smooth duct?

Comment: Moving air will, by default, have turbulence and make noise. The shorter the run, the slower the air flow, and the smoother the duct the less turbulence there will be. Probably the only "silent" cooling you'll get is if you hire a couple of eunuchs to wave palm fronds over you.